# Printing icon missing from "Show Applications" & printing does not happen

Tags: printing, icons, 18.04

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 last week and everything works beautifully except that the *"printing"* icon is missing from "Show Applications".
When I run *"system-config-printer"* from a terminal the *"Printers - localhost"* opens up and shows the network printer.
When I use Synaptic and search for *"system-config-printer-common"* it finds it and shows installed version 1.5.11-1ubuntu2.
When I run *"system-config-printer"* from a terminal the following displays before the app is opened:

```
root@Ubuntu-18:/home/arno# system-config-printer
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)

(system-config-printer:6764): libnotify-WARNING **: 07:14:35.760: Failed to connect to proxy
```

Could this anything to do with the missing icon ?

I tried printing a document and nothing happens. When I right click on the printer and select the *"View Print Queue"* then there are no document in the queue.
In `/var/spool/cups` I find:

```
root@Ubuntu-18:/var/spool/cups# ls -la
total 224
drwx--x--- 3 root lp     4096 May 30 07:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root   4096 May 25 18:12 ..
-rw------- 1 root lp     2684 May 28 10:27 c00001
-rw------- 1 root lp     2684 May 28 10:27 c00002
-rw------- 1 root lp     2684 May 28 10:33 c00003
-rw------- 1 root lp     2668 May 30 07:07 c00004
-rw-r----- 1 root lp    32282 May 28 10:27 d00001-001
-rw-r----- 1 root lp    32282 May 28 10:27 d00002-001
-rw-r----- 1 root lp    32282 May 28 10:33 d00003-001
-rw-r----- 1 root lp   101287 May 30 07:07 d00004-001
drwxrwx--T 2 root lp     4096 May 30 07:07 tmp
```

How do I fix the problem ? 
Please help !

Answer (score 0):

The printing icon is still missing BUT, it may have been deliberately removed by the developers since I can go to "Settings" / "Devices" /  "Printers" and get what I used to have with the Printing icon in Ubuntu 16.04.

The "not printing" problem was solved by using the URL "localhost:631" , select "cups" and then adding the printer. The printing immediately worked when I tested it.